# Placeholder number with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I would like to add a placeholder number in my text, to remind me that I still have to look it up, later. I usually just use something like "XYZ" or "???" for this. But when I'm using the \SI notation I get an error that "?" is not a number.

```latex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    I don't know yet what number to place here: \SI{???}{\percent}.
\end{document}
```

The error I get is:

```latex
siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-number" Invalid token '?' in numerical input. For immediate help type H <return>. ...at number to place here: \SI{???}{\percent}
```

What is the best/suggested way to add a placeholder number or symbol in SI-notation?

Comment: My welcome into the site of TeX.SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pretend that `?` is a valid input 'symbol' such as `\pi`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  input-symbols={?},
}

\begin{document}
    I don't know yet what number to place here: \SI{???}{\percent}.
\end{document}
```

[image: "???\,%" in the output]

The same works for XYZ

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  input-symbols={XYZ},
}

\begin{document}
    I don't know yet what number to place here: \SI{XYZ}{\percent}.
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, you could stop `siunitx` from parsing numbers. Either globally with `\sisetup{parse-numbers=false}` or locally with  `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{???}{\percent}`.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks for the quick answer!
I'm curious, though. Can you explain why there is a small gap between the first and second character, when I use the 'input-symbols={?}' method? It looks something like "? ?? %" or "X YZ %". If I disable number parsing it looks as expected, like "??? %".

Comment: I have understood that the OP didn't know what to put in the place of the ???

Comment: @VincentW. It seems that `siunitx` still groups the `?` as if they were normal digits. In the MWE I get `?`, `??`, `???`, `????`, `??\,???` etc. pp. I do not get `?\,??` though... With `parse-numbers=false` that digit grouping does not happen.

Comment: @moewe I get `?`, `??`, `?\,??`, `?\,?\,??`, `??\,?\,??`. But regular `1234` when I use numbers. Strange... But also not really important. Maybe some language settings...

Comment: @VincentW. Would have been my guess as well, I didn't find anything in the docs on a quick read, though. Do you get that result with my MWE or in your larger document?

Comment: @moewe I'm getting this effect with both the MWE and the larger document.

Comment: @VincentW. Weird. Can you post an image and the complete `.log` file of the MWE? (You can upload the `.log` to a plain text sharing site such as https://pastebin.com/).

Comment: @moewe
Image: ![weird spacing behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5r01.png)
Log file of MWE: https://pastebin.com/4VjreifB

Comment: @VincentW. Your packages are bit old (more than three years for `expl3` and `siunitx`), but other than that I see nothing out of the ordinary. I added a screenshot of the result I get on an up-to-date system. I'm afraid I can't tell you why you get this behaviour.

Comment: @moewe Alright, maybe I'll update my packages. But then again, I think I probably don't care. ;-) Anyway, thanks again for your extensive help! Great stuff!

Comment: @VincentW. It would be interesting to see how normal numbers like `100`, `2000`, `30000`, `400000`, `5000000` are shown. I also wouldn't lose too much sleep over this if it only applies to `?`s.